# How to delete files that are not mp3?

Tags: regex, linux, ubuntu, rm

I have a mp3 Player. I have connected it to my PC which has Ubuntu as an OS.
I want to delete all the files that are not .mp3.

I know that for deleting them the command is rm *.mp3, but what's the combination for negating this?
I've tried: rm ^.mp3, ^mp3 ^[mp3], but they didn't work! Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using `bash` and `extglob` is set, you should be able to:

```
rm !(*.mp3)
```

I would try a test with `ls` before blindly running that command:

```
ls !(*.mp3)
```

To check the value of `extglob`:

```
shopt extglob
```

And to turn it on, if necessary:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: and BTW. Do not just try things with actual rm command. Using something like "echo !(*.mp3)" is a good way of checking what will be actually removed...

Comment: Maybe you add the command to set extglob `shopt -s extglob` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Delete all non-mp3 files:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.mp3' -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU find:

```
find FOLDER -not -iname '*.mp3' -not -type d -delete
```

Which will start from FOLDER, and recursively go through sub folders, deleting any file which doesn't end in mp3 (case insensitive), as long as this file is not a directory.

Comment: the question was to delete all files that are NOT mp3, but thx anyway!

Comment: It now will delete thing that are not mp3

Answer (score 0):

Delete all non-mp3 files recursively from dir

Print them:

```
find dir -type f | egrep -vi "\.mp3$"
```

Delete them

```
find dir -type f | egrep -vi "\.mp3$" | xargs rm -f
```